# Impossible to recover some information with Beautifulsoup on a site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need your help because I have for the first time problems to get some information with Beautifulsoup .

I have two problems on [this page](https://couponscorpion.com/business/agile-project-management-agile-scrum-kanban-xp/)

1. The green button `GET COUPON CODE` appear after a few moment [see GIF capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTrS5.gif)
2. When we inspect the button link, we find a a simple href attribute that call to an `out.php` function that performs the opening of the destination link that I am trying to capture.

```html
<a href="https://couponscorpion.com/scripts/udemy/out.php?go=Q25aTzVXS1l0TXg1TExNZHE5a3pEQmJUcUx0V0JUMyt5QlBPSUdLMGg1U3hYUTFaQ1FKZWhDL1dtQkh5NGFHYUV5U0NwSk1yQ3VMb2d2YUhMMHhiTUJSUmpVK3VIZmNaMk5sT2xkUzBlQ05aSjJCZk45bUtXSGZsbFdQbXVjOFA%3D&amp;s=fb776a44e94d7a31715d75bb381a1eeb350b7f39&amp;n=748036302&amp;a=0" class="btn_offer_block re_track_btn" style="background-color: rgb(102, 178, 44) !important;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">GET COUPON CODE</a>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a little unclear but if I understand correctly, your first problem is that the 'get coupon code' button looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTrS5.gif) when you render the HTML that you receive from the original page request.

The mark-up for a lot of this code is rendered dynamically using javascript. So that button is missing its **href** value until it gets loaded in later. You would need to also run the javascript on that page to render this after the initial request. You can't really get this easily using just the python requests library and BeautifulSoup. It will be a lot easier if you use **Selenium** too which lets you control a browser so it runs all that javascript for you and then you can just get the button info a couple of seconds after loading the page.

There is a way to do this all with plain requests, but it's a bit tedious. You would need to read through the requests the page makes and figure out which one gets the link for the button. The upside to this is it would cut the number of steps to get the info you need and the amount of time it takes to get. You could just use this new request every time to get the right **PHP** link then just get the info from there.

For your second point, I'm also not sure if I answered it already, but maybe you're also trying to get the redirect link from that PHP link. From inspecting the network requests, it looks like the info will be found in the response headers, there is no body to inspect.

[image: Network response]
(I know it says 'from cache' but the point is that the redirect is being caused by the header info)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I will try all your solutions.

Comment: Finally it is too complicated for me with Beautifulsoup because of the JS wich modify the page after it has been loaded.
So I will try now with Selenium hoping that I would not be blocked by CloudFlare as very often.

Comment: @Laurent Sometimes the answer isn't beautifulsoup and HTML parsing. The info you see on the page is being requested with javascript, but you just need to see what those requests and responses are. If you can do the same requests in python, then you'll have that same data. It might come in as json or more HTML, but the data is there for you to request yourself instead of letting selenium do it

Comment: I switched all the scraping to Selenium and I solved all the problems I could have had even on another site.
The discussion we had allowed me to test Selenium to go further, thank you.
The next point now is to add the code to pass the reCAPTCHA when needed.
Thank and have a great day.